# SQLite trigger analyze row data

Tags: android, sqlite, triggers

I have a database with news articles. Each article has a field "categories" which contains ordinals of categories like "3, 7, 9". My point is to create one more table with fields (_id, **article_id**, **category_id**) for many-to-many pattern to provide querying articles by categories.

Is there any way to analyze TEXT field with those numbers from SQLite? To split them by "," and process each number with INSERT. Now I do it with java, but I want to create trigger.

My current code is:

```
private void fillCategoriesTable(Article.Category[] categories, long id) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(Article.KEY_FOREIGN_ARTICLE_ID, id);
    for (Article.Category c : categories) {
        int categoryId = c.ordinal();
        cv.put(Article.KEY_CATEGORY_ID, categoryId);
        mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase().insertOrThrow(ArticlesSqlHelper.DATABASE_CATEGORIES_NAME, null, cv);
    }
}
```

As you can see now I use Enum ordinal number as id for category. If I use trigger, I just need to work with something like "3, 4, 11" and split it by coma to get three different ids. And then make three inserts.

For example here is the trigger for removing rows from **categories** table when I delete from **articles** table

```
private final String REMOVE_CATEGORIES_TRIGGER = "CREATE TRIGGER delete_categories AFTER DELETE " +
        "ON " + DATABASE_ARTICLES_NAME + " FOR EACH ROW " +
        "BEGIN " +
        "DELETE FROM " + DATABASE_CATEGORIES_NAME + " WHERE " + Article.KEY_FOREIGN_ARTICLE_ID + "=" + "OLD." + Article.KEY_ID + "; " +
        "END;";
```

But there is no difficulties because I need only id of article. But when inserting, I need ids of categories too.

Comment: Please post the code that you tried.

Comment: you want to create one more table or database ? and your colum categories is of type varchar containt '3,7,9' right ? and you want insert them into category id 3 and 7 and 9? and at the end you want a triigger for that to do right ?

Comment: Yes. For example if I have article with id 5 and three categories with ids: 3, 7, 9. I need to do three inserts with first value: id of article and second value: id of category.

Comment: Parsing such a list would require a recursive [common table expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html), which is [not allows in triggers](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html), and not guaranteed to be available on every Android version anyway.